# detecting multiple files in a if statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

i have the following bash code written to detect if a SSL certificate exists and if so to skip the creation of one.

i need to expand the list of detected files, so that the presence of any of them will skip the creation of the SSL certificate.

the full list of files are "trailers.cer" or "trailers.key" or "trailers.pem"

An alterntaive approach is after detection, prompt the user asking if they want to create SSL certifictes

```
file="assets/certificates/trailers.cer"
if [ -f "$file" ]; then
echo 'SSL Certificates already created' 
else
openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -out ./assets/certificates/trailers.pem -keyout ./assets/certificates/trailers.key -x509 -days 7300 -subj "/C=US/CN=trailers.apple.com"
openssl x509 -in ./assets/certificates/trailers.pem -outform der -out ./assets/certificates/trailers.cer && cat ./assets/certificates/trailers.key >> ./assets/certificates/trailers.pem
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's sufficient to exit the entire script,

```
for file in trailers.cer trailers.key /assets/certificates/trailers.pem; do
    test -f "$file" && exit 1 # or even 0?
done
# If you reach through here, none existed
```

I changed one of the items to an absolute path just to show how it's done. If the path is the same for all of the files, you could refactor to supply the path later instead; `test -f "/assets/certificates/$file"`

Answer (score 1):

You could put multiple conditions in the `if` using multiple `test` and `||` like this:

```
if test -f "$path1" || test -f "$path2" || test -f "$path3"; then
    ...
fi
```

When there are many files, using an array can be easier and more readable, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

basedir=assets/certificates
files=(trailers.cer trailers.key trailers.pem)

found=
for file in ${files[@]}; do
    path="$basedir/$file"
    if [ -f "$path" ]; then
        echo SSL Certificates already created
        found=1
        break
    fi
done

if test ! "$found"; then
    openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -out ./assets/certificates/trailers.pem -keyout ./assets/certificates/trailers.key -x509 -days 7300 -subj "/C=US/CN=trailers.apple.com"
    openssl x509 -in ./assets/certificates/trailers.pem -outform der -out ./assets/certificates/trailers.cer && cat ./assets/certificates/trailers.key >> ./assets/certificates/trailers.pem
fi
```

Comment: `-o` is deprecated; use `test -f "$path1" || test -f "$path2" || test -f "$path3"` instead.

Comment: Where is that written? In the bash that comes with my up to date Debian testing this is not mentioned in neither `man test` nor `help test`...

Comment: The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) (see the Application Usage section) marks it as obsolescent, due to ambiguities in parsing depending on what other arguments are used.